# Я новичок в Angular, не могу разобраться с корзиной. Суть вопроса видна на картинке приложенной к вопросу. Помогите разобраться

Tags: html, typescript, angular

cart.component.html

```
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover table-dark table-bordered table-sm text-center">
          <thead>
              <tr class="bg-success">
                  <th>№</th>
                  <th>Наименование товара</th>
                  <th>Краткое описание</th>
                  <th>Стоимость товара</th>
                  <th>Количество товара</th>
                  <th>Итого</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr class="br-primary" 
                *ngFor="let item of items; let ind=index">
                  <td>{{ ind+1 }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.discription }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item.price | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2" }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <!-- Напрямую обращение к сервису и вызов в шаблоне методов increase и decrease   -->
                    <button class="btn btnCount" type="button" (click)="cartCounterServices.decrease(item)"> - </button>
                    <span class="span">{{ cartCounterServices.counter }}</span>
                    <button class="btn btnCount" type="button" (click)="cartCounterServices.increase(item)"> + </button>
                    <!-- значение cartCounterServices со значением counter -->
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ (cartCounterServices.counter * item.price) | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2" }}</td>
                      <span class="span" >{{ item.quantity }}</span>
                      <button class="plus-btn" (click)="plus(item)" type="button"> + </button>
                  </td>
                  <td>{{ (item.quantity * item.price) | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2" }}</td>-->
              </tr>
              <td colspan="5">Итого к оплате</td>
              <td colspan="1">{{ grandTotal | currency:"USD":true:"1.2-2" }}</td>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(checkoutForm.value)">
    <div class="d-flex p-0">
        <label class="col-2 p-0">Введите ваше имя:</label>
        <input class="col-4 form-control"  
                type="text" 
                formControlName="name"
            >
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex p-0">
        <label class="col-2 p-0">Введите ваш адрес:</label>
        <input class="col-4 
                form-control" type="text" 
                formControlName="address"
            >
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex"> 
        <label class="col-2 p-0" form="address">Введите ваш телефон:</label>
        <input class="col-4 form-control"  
                type="text" 
                formControlName="number"
            >
    </div>
        <button class="button" type="submit">Заказать</button>
</form>
```

cart.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { CartService } from '../../cart.service';
import { CartCounterServices } from './services/cart-counter.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})

export class CartComponent  {

  title = 'Корзина'
  items = [];//для сохранения товаров в корзине
  checkoutForm;//для хранения модели формы
  public grandTotal: number;

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private cartCounterServices: CartCounterServices ) {    //переменная для работы с сервисом
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();//количество товара при помощи метода getItems() сервиса корзины

    this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      address: '',
      number: ''
    })
  }

  calcGrandTotal(items: any) {
    this.grandTotal = this.items.reduce((acc, item: any)=> {
      return acc + (item.counter * item.price);
    }, 0);
  }

  onSubmit(customerData) {// Обработать данные проверки здесь
    console.warn('Your order has been submitted', customerData);
    this.items = this.cartService.clearCart();
    this.checkoutForm.reset();
  }
}
```

cart.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CartService {
  items = [];//для хранения списка (набора) выбранных товаров в корзине

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  addToCart(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = [];
    return this.items;
  }
}
```

cart-counter.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ 
    providedIn: 'root'// providedIn: 'root' данный сервис регистрирует в корневом модуле
})

export class CartCounterServices {

    public grandTotal: number;
    counter = 1;
    items: [];

    increase(item:any) {
        this.counter++
    }

    decrease(item:any) {
        if(this.counter > 0) {
            this.counter--
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Корзина]

Comment: лучше создавай _воспроизводимые примеры_ на codesandbox, это не сложно, просто переносишь локальный код туда в проект и потом шаришь ссылку и тут. И скриншоты лучше не прикладывать, ты написал, что **Суть вопроса видна на картинке приложенной к вопросу**, честно говоря, я не понял суть вопроса, что на картине

Comment: `(click)="plus(item)"` не вижу метода plus в компоненте :(

Comment: Он реализован в "cart-counter.services.ts" это отдельный сервис который считает количество товаров

Comment: Сервис счетчика один, рутовый. Переменная счетчика в нем одна на все приложение. Честно, не ясно, зачем тебе вообще отдельный сервис для обслуживания счетчика. Держи его рядом с каждым айтемом в основном сервисе, тогда не возникнет таких проблем

Comment: Я пробовал и без сервиса считать количество, в cart.component.ts , такая же проблема

Comment: Еще раз: счетчик один `<span class="span">{{ cartCounterServices.counter }}</span>`. Любая кнопка управляет одним и тем же полем и выводит одно и то же поле. То, что он в лупе создается несколько раз, не значит, что он инициализируется для каждой товарной позиции отдельно. Пересмотрите архитектуру сервиса товаров

Comment: А разграничить это управление в корзине как-то можно, не меняя архитектуру сервиса товаров??? По какой кнопке кликнули, количество соответствующего товара и изменилось

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы хранить кол-во в сервисе (вы ещё и одну переменную для всех товаров используете..) вы добавляйте счетчик в сам товар, в item, и там им манипулируйте уже

Answer (score 0):

У вас `counter` общий для всех добавленных товаров. Чтобы правильно управлять количеством, нужно иметь свой счетчик для каждого отдельного товара.

Для этого можно расширить немного `CartService`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CartService {
  items = new Map(); // ключ - ссылка на товар, значение - счетчик

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addToCart(item) {
    this.items.set(item, 1);
  }

  removeFromCart(item) {
      this.items.delete(item);
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items.keys();
  }

  clearCart() {
    this.items = new Map();
    return this.getItems();
  }

  increment(item) {
    if (this.items.has(item)) {
      this.items.set(item, this.items.get(item) + 1);
    }
  }

  decrement(item) {
    if (this.items.has(item)) {
      this.items.set(item, this.items.get(item) - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Только в темплейте теперь надо будет поправить немного данные. Итерировать не `items`, a `service.getItems()`.

Comment: Спасибо, но вариант не рабочий. Попробую сделать по клику примерно так this.basketItems.find(x => x === item.id || x.id === item.id).count++

Comment: Вариант рабочий, просто не копи-пастой в текущий код. Я изобразил разделение счетчиков и как обрабатывать +/- для разных товаров